# Bug: my UILabel displays on a single cell, how to fix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

My UILabel appears on some cell and times when I scroll my UICollectionView others appear on the cell but not all, how to fix? Thank you

This label mixes with the same label other cell

> // cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
self.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[searchResult objectForKey:@"drawDate"] intValue]];
                    self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [self.dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]]];
                    [self.dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

                cell3.titleContest.hidden = YES;
                cell3.titleContest.alpha = 0;
                //self.dateContest.text = @"";

                NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] init];

                timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

> // countDownTimer

```
- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)tmr
        {
            NSTimeInterval iv = [self.date timeIntervalSinceNow];
            int d = iv / 86400;
            int h = (iv / 3600) - (d * 24);
            int m = (iv - (h + d * 24) * 3600) / 60;
            int s = lroundf(iv) % 60;
            cell3.titleContest.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", d, h, m, s];
            if (d + h + m + s <= 0

) {
                [tmr invalidate];
            }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            cell3.titleContest.hidden = NO;
            cell3.titleContest.alpha = 1;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by table cell recycling, the UICollectionView does not create a completely new cell each time, it will recycle an old cell to use as the new one. you should always reset the state of a cell once it has been dequed in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` then set the appropriate data to make it show its data correctly

from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:):

```
- dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
```

> Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a
>   new cell for the collection view. This method dequeues an existing
>   cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or
>   nib file you previously registered.
>
> IMPORTANT You must register a class or nib file using the
>   registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: or
>   registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: method before calling this
>   method.
>
> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell
>   must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its
>   initWithFrame: method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell
>   object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available
>   for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method
>   instead.

Comment: Yes I understand, but the code I have to put it in the customCell.m?

Comment: the resetting state code? can either be directly in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` or inside your customCell.m in some function that you call from `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: Yes but what is the code to reset? I do not understand

Answer (score 0):

this  is caused due to  recycling cells in order to over come that just alloc the table view cell and continue with out reusing the cells

```
 UITableviwCell *cell = [UITableViewCell alloc]init];
 cell.label.text = ......
```